# php - Calculate different from string

Tags: php

I have 2 string like this `"2018/04/10-14:54:55"` and   `"2018/04/10-14:56:10"`.

How can I calculate different between them? I've used `strtotime` to change the string to date but it gives the wrong value.

Please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you have tried.

Comment: We could point you to the best / most appropriate duplicate if you elaborate a bit more about your expected result.  Rest assured, you are not the first person to want to perform this task.  This IS a duplicate of some pre-existing page(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$time1 = '2018/04/10-14:54:55';
$time2 = '2018/04/10-14:56:10';

$format = 'Y/m/d-H:i:s';
$t1     = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time1);
$t2     = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time2);
echo "time1" . $t1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br/>";
echo "time2" . $t2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br/>";
$difference = $t1->diff($t2);
echo $difference->format('%s%a secs');
```

You can use specific format to create a datetime ojbect, after that you can use diff function to get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
function time_difference($time_1, $time_2, $limit = null)
    {

        $val_1 = new DateTime($time_1);
        $val_2 = new DateTime($time_2);

        $interval = $val_1->diff($val_2);

        $output = array(
            "year" => $interval->y,
            "month" => $interval->m,
            "day" => $interval->d,
            "hour" => $interval->h,
            "minute" => $interval->i,
            "second" => $interval->s
        );

        $return = "";
        foreach ($output AS $key => $value) {

            if ($value == 1)
                $return .= $value . " " . $key . " ";
            elseif ($value >= 1)
                $return .= $value . " " . $key . "s ";

            if ($key == $limit)
                return trim($return);
        }
        return trim($return);
    }


    $time1 = '2018/04/10 14:54:55';
    $time2 = '2018/04/10 14:56:10';

    $resp = time_difference ($time1, $time2);

    echo $resp;
```

output:

```
1 minute 15 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, I have explained the details in the code itself:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran"); //Set your timezone to avoid warnings in PHP error_log



// Use '/' for American date format and use '-' for Europian date format
// Use 'T' instead of '-'
$time_1 = strtotime( str_replace('-', 'T', "2018/04/10-14:54:55") ); //Replace '-' to 'T' to get "2018/04/10T14:54:55"
$time_2 = strtotime( str_replace('-', 'T', "2018/04/10-14:56:10") ); //Replace '-' to 'T' to get "2018/04/10T14:56:10"


$diff = $time_2 - $time_1;

echo $diff; // in seconds

?>
```

I hope it helps.